# Incomprehensible query behaviour

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have multiple tables, related by multiple foreign keys as in the following example:

- `Recipes(id_recipe,name,calories,category)` - `id_recipe` as PK.
- `Ingredients(id_ingredient,name,type)` - `id_ingredient` as PK.
- `Contains(id_ingredient,id_recipe,quantity,unit)` - `(id_ingredient,id_recipe)` as PK, and as Foreign Keys for `Recipes(id_recipe)` and `Ingredients(id_ingredient)`.

You can see this relations represented in this image.
[image]

So basically `Contains` is a bridge between `Recipes` and `Ingredients`.

The query I try to write it's supposed to give as result the names of the recipes whose ingredients type are "bovine" but not "lactic".

My attempt:

`SELECT DISTINCT Recipes.name
FROM Ingredients JOIN Contains USING(id_ingredient) JOIN Recipes USING (id_recipe) 
WHERE Ingredients.type = "bovin" 
AND Ingredients.type <> "lactic";`

The problem is it still shows me recipes that have at least one lactic ingredient.

I would appreciate any help!

Comment: right-ish idea, wrong implementation. you're dealing with sets of data, but your where clause is filtering on a per-row basis - no sets.

Comment: Your query is giving you any recipe containing "bovin", not recipes that do not contain "lactic".

Comment: See for instance http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,507748,507839

Comment: @Uueerdo but, the way is written, isn't it supposed to discard also all the non lactic results?

Comment: No, if you removed the "bovin" part of the WHERE, it would give you any recipe with at least one ingredient that was not "lactic".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the general form of the kind of query you need:

```
SELECT *
FROM tableA
WHERE tableA.ID NOT IN (
   SELECT table_ID
   FROM ...
)
;
```

-- EXAMPLE BELOW --

The subquery gives the id values of all recipes that the "lactic" ingredient is used in, the outer query says "give me all the recipes not in that list".

```
SELECT DISTINCT Recipes.name
FROM Recipes
WHERE id_recipe IN (
   SELECT DISTINCT id_recipe 
   FROM `Ingredients` AS `i`
      INNER JOIN `Contains` AS `c` USING (id_ingredient)
   WHERE `i`.`type` = "lactic"
)
;
```

---

Alternatively, using your original query:
You could've changed the second join to a `LEFT JOIN`, changed it's `USING` to an `ON` & included `AND type = "lactic"` there instead, and ended the query with `HAVING Ingredients.type IS NULL` (or WHERE, I just prefer HAVING for "final result" filtering). This would tell you which items could not be joined to the "lactic" ingredient.

Comment: I think I understand it conceptually, but not enough to actually implement it to this specific case...

Comment: Example above. I just realized I didn't factor in the "bovin" part, that could be accomplished with your original join and where condition on the outer query, or you could add "AND id_recipe IN ( [same subselect query but with ingredient you want] )"

Comment: Following the last instructions it actually worked! As an alternative, it also worked the @axxis version joining Ingredients in nthe second line and adding the condition of selecting bovin. Thanks to you all!

Answer (score 1):

A common solution of this type of question (checking conditions over a set of rows) utilizes aggregate + CASE.

```
SELECT R.Name
FROM Recipes R
INNER JOIN Contains C
 on R.ID_Recipe = C.ID_Recipe
INNER JOIN Ingredients I
 on C.ID_Ingredient = I.ID_Ingredient
GROUP BY R.name
having -- at least one 'lactic' ingredient
  sum(case when type = 'lactic' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
and    -- no 'bovin' ingredient
  sum(case when type = 'bovin' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
```

It's easy to extend to any number of ingredients and any kind of question.

Hijacked the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d4bde1/3) of xQbert

Comment: Although I've adopted a simpler solution seen in other answers, I am interested in learning more. I can't see why do we need to use the `sum()` function, and neither I understand how exactly cases work in this particular situation. I'd appreciate a brief explanation on how the query really works.

Comment: @AlexanderGeorge: Those solutions seem simpler, but you might have to add another subquery for every new ingredient you're looking for.  And you must repeat any WHERE-conditions and/or joins if it's a more complicated query.

Comment: @AlexanderGeorge: SUM over CASE: For every row grouped together by `GROUP BY` the `case when type = 'lactic' then 1 else 0 end` returns either `1` (if `type = 'lactic'`) or `0` (otherwise). When you `SUM` those values you get the number of rows `where type = 'lactic'`, if it's equal to 0 it shows there were no `'lactic'` rows. Same for `'bovin'`, but now there must be at least one  row with that value. To understand how it works you remove the `GROUP BY`, add the `CASE` to the column list and see the details per row.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT R.NAME
FROM CONTAINS C
INNER JOIN INGREDIENTS I
ON I.ID_INGREDIENTS = C.ID_INGREDIENTS AND I.TYPE = 'bovine' AND I.TYPE <> "lactic"
INNER JOIN RECIPES R 
ON R.ID_RECIPE = C.ID_RECIPE
GROUP BY R.NAME
```

That should work, maybe you need to escape 'contains'. It could be recognized as a  SQL function.

Comment: Try this out with some sample data.  Pretty sure you'll find it doesn't work.  I.Type can't be both Bovine and Lactic on the same record. and where clauses process record by record, not set by set.

Comment: Just tried it and it gives me the same results as my first attempt. Shows two correct recipes, but also one that has a lactic ingredient.

Comment: And also tried the second version you posted. Same problem.

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d4bde1/1/0)
 In my example burgers and pasta have 'Bovin' and thus show up.  So do cookies but cookies also have 'lactic' which is why they get excluded.

```
SELECT R.Name
FROM Recipes R
INNER JOIN Contains C
 on R.ID_Recipe = C.ID_Recipe
INNER JOIN Ingredients I
 on C.ID_Ingredient = I.ID_Ingredient
LEFT JOIN (SELECT R2.ID_Recipe
           FROM Ingredients I2
           INNER JOIN Contains C2 
             on C2.ID_Ingredient = I2.ID_Ingredient
           INNER JOIN Recipes R2               
             on R2.ID_Recipe = C2.ID_Recipe
           WHERE Type = 'lactic'
           GROUP BY R2.ID_Recipe) T3
 on T3.ID_Recipe = R.ID_Recipe
WHERE T3.ID_Recipe is null
 and I.Type = 'Bovin'
GROUP BY R.name
```

There likely is a more elegant way of doing this.  I really wanted to CTE this and join it to itself.. but no CTE in mySQL.  Likely a way to do this using exists too....   I'm not a big fan of using IN clauses as the performance generally suffers.  Exists fastest, Joins 2nd fastest, in slowest (generally speaking)

The inline view (sub query) returns the ID_recipe of those you don't want to include.

The outer query returns the Name of the recipes with ingredients you want.

By joining these two together using an outer join we return all recipes and only those with the undesired ingredient.  We then limit the results to only those where the recipe ID doesn't exist for the undesired ingredient.  (undesired ingredient not found) you'll get only those recipes having all desired ingredients.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but couldn't make it work. I found easier solutions in other answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` for this.

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Recipes.`name`
FROM Recipes JOIN Contains AS C1 USING (id_recipe) JOIN Ingredients USING(id_ingredient)
WHERE Ingredients.type = "bovin"
  AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM Contains AS C2 JOIN Ingredients USING(id_ingredient)
    WHERE C1.id_recipe = C2.id_recipe
      AND Ingredients.type = "lactic"
)
```

Comment: It's excluding all the recipes with lactic ingredients, but I still have to specify that they have to be bovin. How do I add this condition in the first WHERE if the first JOIN doesn't include Ingredients?

Comment: @AlexanderGeorge You are right, I forgot bovin. I think I fixed it now.